# Jira plugin that estimates based on past velocity, ala Pivotal Tracker?

Tags: jira, agile, estimation, pivotaltracker

Is there any plugin that makes Jira behave like [Pivotal Tracker](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/) - that is, based on a team's prior velocity, predict when stories in a backlog will be played and put dates on them?

Pivotal Tracker calculated past velocity, and then would put dividers between stories in a backlog based on its estimation of when the team might get to them. This saved a huge amount of hassle, because instead of engineers coming up with date estimates directly, 'the tool' did. It is a great visualisation of prioritisation, because when a stakeholder wants something to get bumped up, everything else gets bumped down and the dates change accordingly.

It'd be great if there was something like this for Jira.